# Почему (65='65ae3ee2-aeb2-427f-8381-56db91b94363') -> TRUE?

Tags: mysql

Запрос `SELECT * FROM families WHERE id = '65ae3ee2-aeb2-427f-8381-56db91b94363' OR fam_code = '65ae3ee2-aeb2-427f-8381-56db91b94363'` возвращает две записи:

```
id fam_code

65 c648b66e-ae0c-467b-af56-1e6d3c214f2e

92 65ae3ee2-aeb2-427f-8381-56db91b94363
```

Почему так?

Comment: а id случайно не числовой тип?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 16):

Вы сравниваете числовое поле с строковым. В этом случае MySQL преобразует строку в число. А при преобразовании строки в число MySQL старается это число составить из всех десятичных цифр с начала строки до первой не цифры. Таким образом при приведении к числу строка `65a...` превращается в число 65.

Проверяется явным приведением типов:

```
select cast('65abc' as unsigned), cast('abc65' as unsigned)

Результат: 65, 0
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: @ДмитрийСелезнев, отметьте ответ принятым