# MySQL: символ A = 0?

Tags: mysql, sql

Писал sql запрос, нашёл ошибку в результатах.

Когда стал детально изучать, увидел косяк в `case ... when ...`. До этого работал с Oracle, он бы такое не пропустил, а MySQL, видимо, кушает всё, что ему дают.

Вопрос - почему выражение `select 'A' = 0` возвращает истину? MySQL видит в символе `A` 0-ю букву алфавита?

**upd:** посмотрел - любое выражение вида `select 'some text' = 0` возвращает истину. MySQL как-то преобразует строку в число?

Comment: Может что то перепутали? `select 'A' = 0` или `where 'A' = 0`

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan ничего не перепутал, именно `select 'A' = 0` для упрощения.

Comment: Ну тогда это правильно ведь  `select 'A' = 0` значит не сравнение а присваивание

Comment: И он возвращает истину потому что смог сделать операцию.

Comment: скажите если я что то перепутал

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan нет, этот запрос выдаст 1 - если уравнение верно и 0 - если неверно. Здесь не может быть никакого присваивания

Comment: можете дать не кусок а целый запрос?

Comment: С точки зрения MySQL все логично. Он всегда переводит строку в число и ошибок, если она не число давать не умеет. Если бы строка начиналась с цифр то результатом было бы это число. А т.к. цифр нет - то результат 0. ну и сравнение уже отрабатывает штатно 0=0 дает истину

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan это и есть целый запрос.

Comment: @Mike непривычны после Oracle такие нюансы.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579208/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-65-65ae3ee2-aeb2-427f-8381-56db91b94363-true/579213#579213

Comment: @Mike даже так, интересно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял это неявное преобразование типов. Вот примеры сравнивания чисел со строками в [mysql](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Comparison_Operators.html).

```
Равно:
mysql> SELECT 1 = 0;
    -> 0
mysql> SELECT '0' = 0;
    -> 1
mysql> SELECT '0.0' = 0;
    -> 1
mysql> SELECT '0.01' = 0;
    -> 0
mysql> SELECT '.01' = 0.01;
    -> 1
```

Comment: но тут именно сравнение строк из символов без цифр с числами

Comment: @Denis Это пример сравнения разных типов данных, и я дал в ответе ссылку на подробное описание.